# Coming back from the future

Tags: science-based

According to Einstein's theory of relativity, if you travel faster than light, time would slow down so I could go into the future. But **how do I come back from the future?** Is there any science proving I could somehow come back from the future and not be stuck there forever?

Comment: There are some inconsistencies in your question, 1) if you travel faster than light, through space, which is as far we know is impossible as your mass becomes infinity, but if you did achieve it through handwavium, you will travel to the past, time travel. 
2) If  you travel at the speed of light or closer to it, (through space) your perception of time will be nonexistent/shorter, thus you would travel to the future.

Comment: This sounds like a pure physics question, which would is off-topic on Worldbuilding.

Comment: Then it would be moved?

Comment: On Physics, it would likely be closed as a duplicate, e.g. of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/is-time-travel-possible-is-it-possible-to-go-back-in-time, so I don't think it's worth migrating. Note, thought, that traveling faster than light brings you to the *past*.

Comment: @spark You are **constantly** travelling to the future. The only thing you can affect is if you are travelling to the future as fast as those around you or not. So travelling near the speed of light does not change the fact that you are travelling the future, you are always doing that. It just means that you can move, say, 100 years into the future while only aging 1 year yourself. As far as science know, Time's Arrow cannot be revered. So no, science says — very sternly — that as far as we know today, you cannot go back in time.

Comment: I meant that the time traveller would be travelling faster into  the future.

Comment: Do you realize that there's a wikipedia page on this? Do some research, spark

Comment: @dunc123 You can hypothetically travel travel faster than light if you solved the problem that prevent it, such as the infinite mass thing could be accounted for by creating a way to get energy from outside of the universe on an as needed basis or using a field that counteracts the field that causes mass in the first place.... or could also do it by figuring out what time is and exploiting it... all of which we "could" do in the future as we're close to these ideas now, but it's unlikely to work so simply imo.

Comment: @Durakken Your comment - and answer - translates to "If we just handwave away all the science that says we cannot travel faster than time...". Yeah well, Spark asked for a science-based answer, not a handwavium-based one.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors No. I'm saying that there are things we know that prevent x. Those things, we can look at the reasons behind and see that it may perhaps be possible to figure out how to get around them, nullifying them as reasons that prevent x. It's called extrapolation and interpolation which what scientists, detectives, theoreticians, wirters, and world builders do all the time.

Comment: @Durakken No... no no no no! If there is anything **scientists** avoid, it is extrapolation. Worldbuilders? Yes. Writers? Yes. Detectives? Yes. Scientists and theoreticists? No. Emphatically **no**. Interpolation? Yes, scientists do that. But this is not interpolation, it is extrapolation. So no... just drop it. There is no science behind your answer and comments at all. It is pure speculation.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Now you're living in a fantasy world. If scientists didn't interpolate and extrapolate they'd have no way of making hypothesis. Anyways, not responding any more because this will just become a "no you" war and this is not the place.

Comment: So do shadows go in the past since they technically have no limit in speed and can be million of times faster than light ?

Comment: @άλεξμιζέρια Shadows are limited in speed by the speed of light.

Comment: but technically objects that move at high speed can cast shadows at unlimited distance, and as we know the greater the distance the larger the shadow will be, right? Therefore this shadow will move at the speed of the object multiplied by it's own size, that technically can surpass speed of light.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The faster you travel the faster outside time is for you and slower it is for you locally. 
If you travel at the speed of light everything happens instantly for you.

That means that if a photon is emitted from the sun, from our perspective it takes 8 minutes to get from the sun to us, but from its perspective that journey happened isntantly.

Now if you go FASTER than light, mathematically, it is interpretted that you start going backwards in time. I am not read up on how the equation bares out but I would assume the faster you go the faster you travel back as well till you hit the same point where you travel so fast all of time is an instant.

Consequences of this is that it a theory that anti-particles are traveling back in time which if true, your ship/person would become anti-particles and it would go boom.

Another 2 ways to travel back in time that is being worked on are Wormholes. If you take a wormhole, open it up and then hold one end and throw it out and then have it come back on side is connected to Time A and the other to Time B and you simply need to go in one end and out the other. Similarly you can use a massive gravity well which is being experimented with.

The problem with both of these, supposing you could get them to work for a human or ship is that you can only go back as far as when the time gate/machine first was able to successfully work. So if these were created in 2020, you went to 2100 and wanted to come back, you could (if the machine was active that whole time) go from 2100 to 2020, but you couldn't go to 2000.
Further, with the Wormhole version you can only go back the set interval. For example, if it was created in 2000 and the other end was in 2050 you could only travel 50 years forward or back (on 1 trip) and only as far back or forward as it was maintained. So if you want to get to 2025 from 2100, you'd have to go back to 2050, then 2000, then wait for 25 years, or conversly wait 25 years and then travel back to 2075 and then 2025. This isn't a problem if you can travel fast though, because you can just travel forward in time to the time interval needed and just go back then.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43196/discussion-on-answer-by-durakken-coming-back-from-the-future). cc@MichaelKarnerfors

Comment: I don't want to argue it, but I'm pretty sure that what was being said in the chat our right and this answer isn't really scientifically accurate.